# Fail in formulary result

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Good morning, I have a problem when send the formulary in my web create with wordpress (it is about a real estate). The result it is correct but appaer a error and I would like correct it.

The fail it is:

strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
/homepages/42/d808315113/htdocs/clickandbuilds/CasaInmobiliaria/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php
on line
489

This is the content in class-wp-block-parser.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Block Serialization Parser
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Class WP_Block_Parser_Block
 *
 * Holds the block structure in memory
 *
 * @since 3.8.0
 */
class WP_Block_Parser_Block {
    /**
     * Name of block
     *
     * @example "core/paragraph"
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var string
     */
    public $blockName;

    /**
     * Optional set of attributes from block comment delimiters
     *
     * @example null
     * @example array( 'columns' => 3 )
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var array|null
     */
    public $attrs;

    /**
     * List of inner blocks (of this same class)
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var WP_Block_Parser_Block[]
     */
    public $innerBlocks;

    /**
     * Resultant HTML from inside block comment delimiters
     * after removing inner blocks
     *
     * @example "...Just <!-- wp:test /--> testing..." -> "Just testing..."
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var string
     */
    public $innerHTML;

    /**
     * List of string fragments and null markers where inner blocks were found
     *
     * @example array(
     *   'innerHTML'    => 'BeforeInnerAfter',
     *   'innerBlocks'  => array( block, block ),
     *   'innerContent' => array( 'Before', null, 'Inner', null, 'After' ),
     * )
     *
     * @since 4.2.0
     * @var array
     */
    public $innerContent;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * Will populate object properties from the provided arguments.
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     *
     * @param string $name         Name of block.
     * @param array  $attrs        Optional set of attributes from block comment delimiters.
     * @param array  $innerBlocks  List of inner blocks (of this same class).
     * @param string $innerHTML    Resultant HTML from inside block comment delimiters after removing inner blocks.
     * @param array  $innerContent List of string fragments and null markers where inner blocks were found.
     */
    function __construct( $name, $attrs, $innerBlocks, $innerHTML, $innerContent ) {
        $this->blockName    = $name;
        $this->attrs        = $attrs;
        $this->innerBlocks  = $innerBlocks;
        $this->innerHTML    = $innerHTML;
        $this->innerContent = $innerContent;
    }
}

/**
 * Class WP_Block_Parser_Frame
 *
 * Holds partial blocks in memory while parsing
 *
 * @internal
 * @since 3.8.0
 */
class WP_Block_Parser_Frame {
    /**
     * Full or partial block
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var WP_Block_Parser_Block
     */
    public $block;

    /**
     * Byte offset into document for start of parse token
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var int
     */
    public $token_start;

    /**
     * Byte length of entire parse token string
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var int
     */
    public $token_length;

    /**
     * Byte offset into document for after parse token ends
     * (used during reconstruction of stack into parse production)
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var int
     */
    public $prev_offset;

    /**
     * Byte offset into document where leading HTML before token starts
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var int
     */
    public $leading_html_start;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Will populate object properties from the provided arguments.
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     *
     * @param WP_Block_Parser_Block $block              Full or partial block.
     * @param int                   $token_start        Byte offset into document for start of parse token.
     * @param int                   $token_length       Byte length of entire parse token string.
     * @param int                   $prev_offset        Byte offset into document for after parse token ends.
     * @param int                   $leading_html_start Byte offset into document where leading HTML before token starts.
     */
    function __construct( $block, $token_start, $token_length, $prev_offset = null, $leading_html_start = null ) {
        $this->block              = $block;
        $this->token_start        = $token_start;
        $this->token_length       = $token_length;
        $this->prev_offset        = isset( $prev_offset ) ? $prev_offset : $token_start + $token_length;
        $this->leading_html_start = $leading_html_start;
    }
}

/**
 * Class WP_Block_Parser
 *
 * Parses a document and constructs a list of parsed block objects
 *
 * @since 3.8.0
 * @since 4.0.0 returns arrays not objects, all attributes are arrays
 */
class WP_Block_Parser {
    /**
     * Input document being parsed
     *
     * @example "Pre-text\n<!-- wp:paragraph -->This is inside a block!<!-- /wp:paragraph -->"
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var string
     */
    public $document;

    /**
     * Tracks parsing progress through document
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var int
     */
    public $offset;

    /**
     * List of parsed blocks
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var WP_Block_Parser_Block[]
     */
    public $output;

    /**
     * Stack of partially-parsed structures in memory during parse
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @var WP_Block_Parser_Frame[]
     */
    public $stack;

    /**
     * Empty associative array, here due to PHP quirks
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     * @var array empty associative array
     */
    public $empty_attrs;

    /**
     * Parses a document and returns a list of block structures
     *
     * When encountering an invalid parse will return a best-effort
     * parse. In contrast to the specification parser this does not
     * return an error on invalid inputs.
     *
     * @since 3.8.0
     *
     * @param string $document Input document being parsed.
     * @return WP_Block_Parser_Block[]
     */
    function parse( $document ) {
        $this->document    = $document;
        $this->offset      = 0;
        $this->output      = array();
        $this->stack       = array();
        $this->empty_attrs = json_decode( '{}', true );

        do {
            // twiddle our thumbs.
        } while ( $this->proceed() );

        return $this->output;
    }

    /**
     * Processes the next token from the input document
     * and returns whether to proceed eating more tokens
     *
     * This is the "next step" function that essentially
     * takes a token as its input and decides what to do
     * with that token before descending deeper into a
     * nested block tree or continuing along the document
     * or breaking out of a level of nesting.
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @return bool
     */
    function proceed() {
        $next_token = $this->next_token();
        list( $token_type, $block_name, $attrs, $start_offset, $token_length ) = $next_token;
        $stack_depth = count( $this->stack );

        // we may have some HTML soup before the next block.
        $leading_html_start = $start_offset > $this->offset ? $this->offset : null;

        switch ( $token_type ) {
            case 'no-more-tokens':
                // if not in a block then flush output.
                if ( 0 === $stack_depth ) {
                    $this->add_freeform();
                    return false;
                }

                /*
                 * Otherwise we have a problem
                 * This is an error
                 *
                 * we have options
                 * - treat it all as freeform text
                 * - assume an implicit closer (easiest when not nesting)
                 */

                // for the easy case we'll assume an implicit closer.
                if ( 1 === $stack_depth ) {
                    $this->add_block_from_stack();
                    return false;
                }

                /*
                 * for the nested case where it's more difficult we'll
                 * have to assume that multiple closers are missing
                 * and so we'll collapse the whole stack piecewise
                 */
                while ( 0 < count( $this->stack ) ) {
                    $this->add_block_from_stack();
                }
                return false;

            case 'void-block':
                /*
                 * easy case is if we stumbled upon a void block
                 * in the top-level of the document
                 */
                if ( 0 === $stack_depth ) {
                    if ( isset( $leading_html_start ) ) {
                        $this->output[] = (array) self::freeform(
                            substr(
                                $this->document,
                                $leading_html_start,
                                $start_offset - $leading_html_start
                            )
                        );
                    }

                    $this->output[] = (array) new WP_Block_Parser_Block( $block_name, $attrs, array(), '', array() );
                    $this->offset   = $start_offset + $token_length;
                    return true;
                }

                // otherwise we found an inner block.
                $this->add_inner_block(
                    new WP_Block_Parser_Block( $block_name, $attrs, array(), '', array() ),
                    $start_offset,
                    $token_length
                );
                $this->offset = $start_offset + $token_length;
                return true;

            case 'block-opener':
                // track all newly-opened blocks on the stack.
                array_push(
                    $this->stack,
                    new WP_Block_Parser_Frame(
                        new WP_Block_Parser_Block( $block_name, $attrs, array(), '', array() ),
                        $start_offset,
                        $token_length,
                        $start_offset + $token_length,
                        $leading_html_start
                    )
                );
                $this->offset = $start_offset + $token_length;
                return true;

            case 'block-closer':
                /*
                 * if we're missing an opener we're in trouble
                 * This is an error
                 */
                if ( 0 === $stack_depth ) {
                    /*
                     * we have options
                     * - assume an implicit opener
                     * - assume _this_ is the opener
                     * - give up and close out the document
                     */
                    $this->add_freeform();
                    return false;
                }

                // if we're not nesting then this is easy - close the block.
                if ( 1 === $stack_depth ) {
                    $this->add_block_from_stack( $start_offset );
                    $this->offset = $start_offset + $token_length;
                    return true;
                }

                /*
                 * otherwise we're nested and we have to close out the current
                 * block and add it as a new innerBlock to the parent
                 */
                $stack_top                        = array_pop( $this->stack );
                $html                             = substr( $this->document, $stack_top->prev_offset, $start_offset - $stack_top->prev_offset );
                $stack_top->block->innerHTML     .= $html;
                $stack_top->block->innerContent[] = $html;
                $stack_top->prev_offset           = $start_offset + $token_length;

                $this->add_inner_block(
                    $stack_top->block,
                    $stack_top->token_start,
                    $stack_top->token_length,
                    $start_offset + $token_length
                );
                $this->offset = $start_offset + $token_length;
                return true;

            default:
                // This is an error.
                $this->add_freeform();
                return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Scans the document from where we last left off
     * and finds the next valid token to parse if it exists
     *
     * Returns the type of the find: kind of find, block information, attributes
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @since 4.6.1 fixed a bug in attribute parsing which caused catastrophic backtracking on invalid block comments
     * @return array
     */
    function next_token() {
        $matches = null;

        /*
         * aye the magic
         * we're using a single RegExp to tokenize the block comment delimiters
         * we're also using a trick here because the only difference between a
         * block opener and a block closer is the leading `/` before `wp:` (and
         * a closer has no attributes). we can trap them both and process the
         * match back in PHP to see which one it was.
         */
        $has_match = preg_match(
            '/<!--\s+(?P<closer>\/)?wp:(?P<namespace>[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*\/)?(?P<name>[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*)\s+(?P<attrs>{(?:(?:[^}]+|}+(?=})|(?!}\s+\/?-->).)*+)?}\s+)?(?P<void>\/)?-->/s',
            $this->document,
            $matches,
            PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,
            $this->offset
        );

        // if we get here we probably have catastrophic backtracking or out-of-memory in the PCRE.
        if ( false === $has_match ) {
            return array( 'no-more-tokens', null, null, null, null );
        }

        // we have no more tokens.
        if ( 0 === $has_match ) {
            return array( 'no-more-tokens', null, null, null, null );
        }

        list( $match, $started_at ) = $matches[0];

        $length    = strlen( $match );
        $is_closer = isset( $matches['closer'] ) && -1 !== $matches['closer'][1];
        $is_void   = isset( $matches['void'] ) && -1 !== $matches['void'][1];
        $namespace = $matches['namespace'];
        $namespace = ( isset( $namespace ) && -1 !== $namespace[1] ) ? $namespace[0] : 'core/';
        $name      = $namespace . $matches['name'][0];
        $has_attrs = isset( $matches['attrs'] ) && -1 !== $matches['attrs'][1];

        /*
         * Fun fact! It's not trivial in PHP to create "an empty associative array" since all arrays
         * are associative arrays. If we use `array()` we get a JSON `[]`
         */
        $attrs = $has_attrs
            ? json_decode( $matches['attrs'][0], /* as-associative */ true )
            : $this->empty_attrs;

        /*
         * This state isn't allowed
         * This is an error
         */
        if ( $is_closer && ( $is_void || $has_attrs ) ) {
            // we can ignore them since they don't hurt anything.
        }

        if ( $is_void ) {
            return array( 'void-block', $name, $attrs, $started_at, $length );
        }

        if ( $is_closer ) {
            return array( 'block-closer', $name, null, $started_at, $length );
        }

        return array( 'block-opener', $name, $attrs, $started_at, $length );
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new block object for freeform HTML
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.9.0
     *
     * @param string $innerHTML HTML content of block.
     * @return WP_Block_Parser_Block freeform block object.
     */
    function freeform( $innerHTML ) {
        return new WP_Block_Parser_Block( null, $this->empty_attrs, array(), $innerHTML, array( $innerHTML ) );
    }

    /**
     * Pushes a length of text from the input document
     * to the output list as a freeform block.
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @param null $length how many bytes of document text to output.
     */
    function add_freeform( $length = null ) {
        $length = $length ? $length : strlen( $this->document ) - $this->offset;

        if ( 0 === $length ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->output[] = (array) self::freeform( substr( $this->document, $this->offset, $length ) );
    }

    /**
     * Given a block structure from memory pushes
     * a new block to the output list.
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @param WP_Block_Parser_Block $block        The block to add to the output.
     * @param int                   $token_start  Byte offset into the document where the first token for the block starts.
     * @param int                   $token_length Byte length of entire block from start of opening token to end of closing token.
     * @param int|null              $last_offset  Last byte offset into document if continuing form earlier output.
     */
    function add_inner_block( WP_Block_Parser_Block $block, $token_start, $token_length, $last_offset = null ) {
        $parent                       = $this->stack[ count( $this->stack ) - 1 ];
        $parent->block->innerBlocks[] = (array) $block;
        $html                         = substr( $this->document, $parent->prev_offset, $token_start - $parent->prev_offset );

        if ( ! empty( $html ) ) {
            $parent->block->innerHTML     .= $html;
            $parent->block->innerContent[] = $html;
        }

        $parent->block->innerContent[] = null;
        $parent->prev_offset           = $last_offset ? $last_offset : $token_start + $token_length;
    }

    /**
     * Pushes the top block from the parsing stack to the output list.
     *
     * @internal
     * @since 3.8.0
     * @param int|null $end_offset byte offset into document for where we should stop sending text output as HTML.
     */
    function add_block_from_stack( $end_offset = null ) {
        $stack_top   = array_pop( $this->stack );
        $prev_offset = $stack_top->prev_offset;

        $html = isset( $end_offset )
            ? substr( $this->document, $prev_offset, $end_offset - $prev_offset )
            : substr( $this->document, $prev_offset );

        if ( ! empty( $html ) ) {
            $stack_top->block->innerHTML     .= $html;
            $stack_top->block->innerContent[] = $html;
        }

        if ( isset( $stack_top->leading_html_start ) ) {
            $this->output[] = (array) self::freeform(
                substr(
                    $this->document,
                    $stack_top->leading_html_start,
                    $stack_top->token_start - $stack_top->leading_html_start
                )
            );
        }

        $this->output[] = (array) $stack_top->block;
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is in this script (is the line 488 to 496) but I can not repair.

```
    function add_freeform( $length = null ) {
        $length = $length ? $length : strlen( $this->document ) - $this->offset;

        if ( 0 === $length ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->output[] = (array) self::freeform( substr( $this->document, $this->offset, $length ) );
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if it is an array, use `count` rather than `strlen`

Comment: `strlen` works with string value datatype, `$this->document` seems to be an array/object and can't be used with `strlen` at all. The same with `substr` which placed in the end of that method.

Comment: It is a core Wordpress code. The problem is related to what you do. What causes this error (you save a post or something else)? Please, give some details

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing us `var_dump($this->document)`

Comment: I found the same issue [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/couldnt-edit-poll-due-to-class-wp-block-parser-php-on-line-417-wp-5-3-2/). Update your plugins and Wordpress

Comment: The plugins were update and I have the same error. If I change count with strlen appear more fails: Warning
: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
/homepages/42/d808315113/htdocs/clickandbuilds/CasaInmobiliaria/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php
on line
489

Comment: This is the seeker about houses, appear the correct results but the error show in the top of the page.

Comment: Where I can found var_dump($this->document)?

Comment: Add `var_dump($this->document);` after `function add_freeform( $length = null ) {` and show the output

Comment: Appear that:
string(8) "Meta Box" string(10) "MetaBox.io" string(56) "Create custom meta boxes and custom fields in WordPress." string(7) "4.14.11" string(14) "Estatik Native"
Warning
: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
/homepages/42/d808315113/htdocs/clickandbuilds/CasaInmobiliaria/wp-includes/class-wp-block-parser.php
on line
417